# cam-bpd-ui pod doesn't start successfully after CAM fresh install

Tags: ibm-cloud-private, cloud-automation-manager

After a CAM 2.1.0.2 fresh install on ICP, by running the following command:

```
kubectl -n services get pods
```

I noticed that "cam-bpd-ui" pod didn't start. So I'm not able to log in to Process Designer UI and I'm getting the error: `"Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 404".`

According to the ICP overview pane it is running and available. However I see this in the logs

```
 "[Warning] Failed to load slave replication state from table mysql.gtid_slave_pos: 1146: Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist
Version: '10.1.16-MariaDB-1~jessie'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
2018-04-24 16:15:52 140411194034112 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections."
```

When checking the events in the cam-bpd-ui pod we see the following:

```
kubectl describe pod cam-bpd-ui-687764b5fc-qxjnp -n services
Name:           cam-bpd-ui-687764b5fc-qxjnp
Namespace:      services
```

...

```
Events:
  Type     Reason                 Age                 From                     Message
  ----     ------                 ----                ----                     -------
  Normal   Scheduled              27m                 default-scheduler        Successfully assigned cam-bpd-ui-687764b5fc-qxjnp to 10.190.155.237
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  27m                 kubelet, 10.190.155.237  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "default-token-c8nq4"
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  27m                 kubelet, 10.190.155.237  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "cam-logs-pv"
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  27m                 kubelet, 10.190.155.237  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "cam-bpd-appdata-pv"
  Normal   Pulled                 27m                 kubelet, 10.190.155.237  Container image "icp-dev.watsonplatform.net:8500/services/icam-busybox:2.1.0.2-x86_64" already present on machine
  Normal   Created                27m                 kubelet, 10.190.155.237  Created container
  Normal   Pulled                 27m                 kubelet, 10.190.155.237  Container image "icp-dev.watsonplatform.net:8500/services/icam-bpd-ui:2.1.0.2-x86_64" already present on machine
  Normal   Started                27m                 kubelet, 10.190.155.237  Started container
  Normal   Created                27m                 kubelet, 10.190.155.237  Created container
  Normal   Started                27m                 kubelet, 10.190.155.237  Started container
  Warning  Unhealthy              26m (x2 over 26m)   kubelet, 10.190.155.237  Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.1.45.36:8080/landscaper/login: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
  Warning  BackOff                12m (x3 over 12m)   kubelet, 10.190.155.237  Back-off restarting failed container
  Warning  Unhealthy              2m (x129 over 26m)  kubelet, 10.190.155.237  Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 404
```

Comment: Please read: [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

The Process Designer (BPD) needs to connect to the mariadb so that it can populate.
You need to be 100% sure that the db is functional. If it is not, bpd will not return the login page for you.

Some hints:

1) If you have an NFS, ensure that /etc/exports has /export *(rw,insecure,no_subtree_check,async,no_root_squash)

For more details about no_root_squash you can see the link here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nfs-mount-on-ubuntu-16-04

As workaround you can do the following:

you can setup your own db and configure so that the BPD uses it.
Details can be found here:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS4GSP_6.2.7/com.ibm.edt.doc/topics/install_database_mysql_bds.html